# output not displaying inside the array

Tags: javascript

```js
const pyramidOfAsterisks = function(val) {
  var arr=[];
  for (let m = 1; m <= val; m++) {
      if (m === 7)
          break;
      for (let s = 1; s <= val - m; s++) {
          document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp");
      }
      for (let n = 1; n <= m; n++) {
          document.write("* ");
      }
      for (let p = 2; p <= m; p++) {

          document.write("* ");
      }
      document.write("<br />");

      arr.push()
  }
} 


var pyramid = pyramidOfAsterisks(12);
        document.write(pyramid);
```

I have tried to display the output inside the given empty array., so i pushed the function into the array , but not displaying inside the array.

Comment: The function does not return anything

Comment: Also, check de errors in the console

Comment: #0stone0 , it only displaying the star pattern, but not inside the array. i want to print inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

1. You never push anything to the array `arr`
2. You never return anything in `pyramidOfAsterisks` [which is why it prints `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Replace `document.write` with `arr.push` and return `arr` before the end of `pyramidOfAsterisks`.

```js
const pyramidOfAsterisks = function(val) {
  var arr=[];
  for (let m = 1; m <= val; m++) {
      if (m === 7)
          break;
      for (let s = 1; s <= val - m; s++) {
          arr.push("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp");
      }
      for (let n = 1; n <= m; n++) {
          arr.push("* ");
      }
      for (let p = 2; p <= m; p++) {

          arr.push("* ");
      }
      arr.push("<br />");

      //arr.push()
  };

  return arr
} 

//REM: Be aware of array.join
var pyramid = pyramidOfAsterisks(12);
document.write(pyramid.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `arr.push()` function input the value you want to add to the array.

For example

```
arr.push("one")
arr.push("two")

// It will return ["one","two"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const pyramidOfAsterisks = function(val) {
// var arr=[];
for (let m = 1; m <= val; m++) {
  if (m === 7)
      break;
  for (let s = 1; s <= val - m; s++) {
      document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp");
  }
  for (let n = 1; n <= m; n++) {
      document.write("* ");
  }
  for (let p = 2; p <= m; p++) {

      document.write("* ");
  }
  document.write("<br />");

  // arr.push()
 }
} 


var pyramid = pyramidOfAsterisks(12);
    // document.write(pyramid);
```

This code works fine. It outputs `undefined` because of the document.write in the end. `pyramidOfAsterisks` does not return any value yet you assign the value it returns to a variable named pyramid, this is why `pyramid` is equal to `undefined`